Changing Terminal font size using script?
I am currently making a terminal app, and wanted to allow user to change zoom of a windows 11 terminal. Is there a way to change Font size or any other way?
As I didn't find anything to do it, and I tried pynput to do it "manually", and it didn't work. I looked for ways to change font size without having the user making it manually. I also tried ANSI escape codes, but didn't work either. (Please don't mind if there are errors in the following scripts, as I deleted all past attemps)
from pynput.keyboard import Controller, Key
    keyboard = Controller()
    while True:
        x,y = get_terminal_size()
        print(f"Actual setting : {x}x{y}")
        ch = input("Increase or decrease quality (+/-)(enter to exit) : ")
        if ch == "+":
            with keyboard.pressed(Key.ctrl):
                Press(KEYPAD_MINUS)
        elif ch == "-":
            with keyboard.pressed(Key.ctrl):
                Press(KEYPAD_PLUS)
        elif ch == "":
            break
        else:
            print("")

from pynput.keyboard import Controller, Key
    keyboard = Controller()
    while True:
        x,y = get_terminal_size()
        print(f"Actual setting : {x}x{y}")
        ch = input("Increase or decrease quality (+/-)(enter to exit) : ")
        if ch == "+":
            size += 10
            print(f"\033[{size}m", end='')
        elif ch == "-":
            size -= 10
            print(f"\033[{size}m", end='')
        elif ch == "":
            break
        else:
            print("")```


No. ANSI terminal protocols were developed back when terminals were dedicated hardware with a fixed set of cells (typically 80x25) controlled over a serial line. There's no concept of "font" at all.

The code-example isn't related to anything except possibly the (mostly-undocumented) Windows Terminal.

you can change font size of terminal in corresponding field of settings.json of a terminal

The following code worked for me:
from pynput.keyboard import Controller, Key
keyboard = Controller()
while True:
    x,y = get_terminal_size()
    print(f"Actual setting : {x}x{y}")
    ch = input("Increase or decrease quality (+/-)(enter to exit) : ")
    if ch == "+":
        with keyboard.pressed(Key.ctrl):
            keyboard.press('+')
        print('increased')
    elif ch == "-":
        with keyboard.pressed(Key.ctrl):
            keyboard.press('-')
        print('decreased')
    elif ch == "":
        break
    else:
        print("unknown command")

Compared to the code from the question it looks important that the code above uses keyboard.press('+') not KEYPAD_MINUS.
Here is a session in the terminal:
(venv_pynput) PS ...\venv_pynput> python .\my_scripts\so_79020368.py
Actual setting : 144x38
Increase or decrease quality (+/-)(enter to exit) : +
increased
Actual setting : 144x38
Increase or decrease quality (+/-)(enter to exit) : +
increased
Actual setting : 134x35
Increase or decrease quality (+/-)(enter to exit) : -
decreased
Actual setting : 125x33
Increase or decrease quality (+/-)(enter to exit) : -
decreased
Actual setting : 134x35
Increase or decrease quality (+/-)(enter to exit) :
(venv_pynput) PS ...\venv_pynput>

